# Extending ReactiveCocoa

Tags: swift, swift2, reactive-cocoa

I'm using ReactiveCocoa 4.0.4 alpha 1 and Swift 2.1. I'm trying to write an extension that creates a max text limit on a `UITextField`.

```
extension RACStream {
    public func max(textField: UITextField, max: Int) -> RACStream! {

        return filter { next in
            if let str = next as? String {
                let ret = str.characters.count < max
                if !ret {
                    textField.text = str[0..<max-1]
                }
                return ret
            }
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
self.inputTextField.rac_textSignal()
    .max(self.inputTextField, max: 7)
    .throttle(0.25)
    .subscribeNext { (obj: AnyObject!) -> Void in
        let input = Int(obj as! String)
        print(input)
     }
```

I get an error when I try to call `max`. It tells me `Value of type RACStream has no member throttle`. It gives a similar error if I call `max` after `throttle`.

I took a look at the `RACStream` class inspect filter. Being it returns `Self!`, which refers to `RACStream`, I would assume that when I extend the class, by return an `RACStream!` would result in similar behavior. Why won't the rest of my pipeline respond to my extended function?

Comment: Try to return with `self` filter : `return self.filter{ //////// }`

Comment: @ProblemSlover No difference, still the same error message

Comment: What about return the block like  
return  `self.filter {  (val: Bool ) -> ()  next in  /// Your code   }`

Comment: I just tried `return self.filter { (next: AnyObject!) -> Bool in /// }` with the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [source code](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/master/ReactiveCocoa/Objective-C/RACSignal%2BOperations.h)  methods `throttle`, `subscribeNext` are members  of  class `RACSignal` (it's  a subclass of `RACStream`), but your extension method is intended for class `RACStream` and you call the method `rac_textSignal()` which returns type `RACSignal` . Therefore, In order to eliminate an error described in your question you should write an extension for `RACSignal` rather than `RACStream`.

```
 extension RACSignal {
         public func max(textField: UITextField, max: Int) -> RACSignal {

         // method filter can be invoked since RACSignal is subclass of RACStream

           return filter { next in
                    if let str = next as? String {
                        let ret = str.characters.count < max
                        if !ret {
                            textField.text = str[0..<max-1]
                        }
                        return ret
                    }
                    return true
                } 

          }  // Func

} // RacSignal Ext
```

Comment: @Chris You are welcome.  I'm Glad it was helpful for you :)